# Trouble calculating the sum of a column (type Number) from Parse.com localDatastore?

Tags: java, android, database, arraylist, parse-platform

[image: My table , and the column i need the total value of in red]

Hi, 
Could someone please help me with parse.com querying and calculating.
I want to calculate the total sum of a column (DEBT) in parse.com from my localDatastore, or from web if first option is not possible.
I have tried storing the elements in an array-list but without success.
So how do I do that?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse does not support `SUM` queries. Here is the [official statement](https://parse.com/questions/calculations-on-queries).

Anyway, you need to use cloud code or to get all rows to achieve what you want (sadly) client-side.

**EDIT**

On client-side, make a `ParseQuery.findInBackground()` request and go through all items, adding values to make the `SUM` client-side.

```
new ParseQuery<Whatever>("WHATEVER")
    .findInBackground(new FindCallback<Whatever>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Whatever> list, ParseException e) {
            // check for ParseException
            Integer sum = 0;
            for (final Whatever whatever : list) {
                sum += (Integer) whatever.get("Debt");
            }
            // there is your SUM
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanx , I know that, but could you at least help me how to store all values of a certain column in an array or arraylist , and then I could do the calculation from there, thanks again..

Comment: Client-side code is simple. Got a snippet for you. Does that help?

Comment: yeah thats nice , just some problems , 
so could you please fill the code (whatevers) for me out.
Name of the Table is "Borxhet" , name of the column is "Debt" , type of the sum must be double , so if you  need anything else just tell me..

Comment: Whatever is just your Java Class, WHATEVER is the Parse class name... Simple search & replace. Refer to `ParseQuery` documentation please...